# How to use Dr Watson debugging tool

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

I came across my friend speaking about Dr watson tool in a recent get together, for using in case of app crash.I googled about it and opened it through - System Information -> Tools -> Dr Watson.
How does this tool work? 
How can I get info from this tool when my VC++ application crashes?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: [Related knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308538).

Comment: It was removed from Windows quite a while ago.  These days you just create a minidump from Taskmgr.exe and open it in your debugger.

Answer (score 1):

This link would help - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275481.

Dr Watson is a tool which automatically takes dump of the memory when any application crashes. Using those dumps , you can used debugger like Windbg to anlayze the reason for the crash. This tool was part of Windows XP. You can activate this tool by running "drwtsn32.exe" from command prompt.

In windows7 you can create a dump by using TaskManager by right clicking on a process.
In Win XP, you can create a dump using [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).